# Java get random string from arraylist

Tags: java

**Note:** I read other posts and I tried to apply it to my own text and this is the result of it.

**Question:** What do I have to change or add to my code to make it work properly?

**Errors:**

```
error: cannot find symbol
error: cannot find symbol
```

these are the following lines: 134, 135.

```
int n = r.nextInt(lijst.size() ) ;
kies KiesNaam = lijst.get( n );
```

**This is the class:**

```
class kies implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
        Random r = new Random();
        int n = r.nextInt(lijst.size() ) ;
        kies chooseName = lijst.get( n );
        textvak2.setText("" + KiesNaam );
    }
}
```

**This is what I'm trying to achieve:** Push the button kiesWin to make the program choose a random person from the ArrayList. The random chosen person's name should appear in the JTexstField textvak2.

**In Case you need the whole code:** (Scroll all the way down for the class kies)

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

// Main method to make the frame
public class Loterij3 extends JFrame {
public static void main( String args[] ) {
    JFrame frame = new Loterij3();
    frame.setExtendedState( frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH );
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    frame.setTitle( "My Lottery!" );
    frame.setContentPane( new Paneel() );
    frame.setVisible( true );
}
}

class Paneel extends JPanel {
private boven boven;
JTextArea textvak1;
JTextField textvak2;
OnthoudNaam onthoudNaam = new OnthoudNaam();
JTextField invoervak1;

public Paneel() {
setLayout( new BorderLayout() ); // using border Layout.
setBackground( Color.LIGHT_GRAY );

boven = new boven(); 

textvak1 = new JTextArea();
add( new JScrollPane( textvak1 ) );
textvak1.setBackground( Color.WHITE );

textvak2 = new JTextField();
textvak2.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
textvak2.setEditable( false );  

add( boven, BorderLayout.NORTH );
add( textvak1, BorderLayout.CENTER );
add( textvak2, BorderLayout.SOUTH );
}


public class boven extends JPanel {
JButton kiesWin, resetL;
JLabel label1;

public boven() {
    setBackground( Color.LIGHT_GRAY );
    setLayout( new GridLayout( 1, 4, 100, 5 ) ); // using GridLayout.
    Border border = 
        BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder( 10, 10, 10, 10 );
    setBorder( border );

    kiesWin = new JButton("Kies een Winnaar!");
    kiesWin.addActionListener( new kies() );
    resetL = new JButton("Reset alles");
    resetL.addActionListener( new reset() );
    label1 = new JLabel("Voer Persoon in en druk op enter: ", JLabel.RIGHT);
    invoervak1 = new JTextField( 20 );
    invoervak1.addActionListener( new InvoerVakHandler() );

    add( label1 );
    add( invoervak1 );
    add( kiesWin );
    add( resetL );
    }
}

// de naam
class naam {
    private String ingevoerdNaam;

    public naam( String ingevoerdNaam) {
        this.ingevoerdNaam = ingevoerdNaam;
    }

    public String getIngevoerdNaam() {
        return ingevoerdNaam;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return ingevoerdNaam;
    }
}

// Arraylist
class OnthoudNaam extends JPanel {
    private ArrayList<naam> lijst;

    public OnthoudNaam() {
        lijst = new ArrayList<naam>();
        }

        public void voegNaamToe(naam x ) {
        lijst.add(x);
        }

        public String toString() {
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        for(naam x : lijst ) {
        buffer.append( x );
        buffer.append( "\n" );
    }
    return buffer.toString();
}
}

// invoer handler
public class InvoerVakHandler implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
        String invoer = invoervak1.getText();
        naam naam = new naam( invoer );
        onthoudNaam.voegNaamToe( naam );
        textvak1.setText( onthoudNaam.toString() );
        invoervak1.setText( "" );
    }
}
    // This is the part where it goes wrong.
class kies implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
        Random r = new Random();
        int n = r.nextInt(lijst.size() ) ;
        kies chooseName = lijst.get( n );
        textvak2.setText("" + KiesNaam );
    }
}

// reset
class reset implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
    }
}
}
```

**For everyone who is trying to help me: Thank you for all your help and patience in advance!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to use `lijst` within `kies` - but it's not a member of `kies`, or any superclass of `kies`, or the implicit enclosing instance of `kies`. It's a member of `OnthoudNaam`.

So you either need to change where you're trying to use it, or have an instance of `OnthoudNaam` to fetch it from.

Yet *again*, this would all be simpler if you'd stop using all these inner classes (and classes which don't follow Java naming conventions). Please don't keep just ploughing on with the messy code - if you take a step back and make your existing code much cleaner, you won't have nearly as many problems going forward.

Comment: Not that it belonging to a superclass would help, since it is private.

Comment: @Keppil: True - although then at least it would be easier to solve (e.g. via an accessor method).

Answer (score 1):

private ArrayList lijst;
(Having your code in Dutch is not the best practice, especially if you are going to work with foreign people).

That variable is private which means that no other class outside of the class defining it can reach it. The only class that has access to it right now is OnthoudNaam. Any function or class outside of the OnthoudNaam class does not know about the existence of your list (lijst). What you have to do to make this work is to make the lijst variable available to kies.

Maybe a nice place to start studying public, private, protected and such:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html